# Cordova SQLite with ionic native in angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I'd like to add DeepLinking to my hybrid application which I found out works with ionic-native. 
I have a working project with SQLite datebase tested on iOS and android but when I include `ionic.native` in my app module it throws an error.

app.module: `angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ionic.native'])`
app.run: openDB is at app.js:207
`ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
  db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'my.db', location: 'default'});
});`

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. app.js:207

[The blog post about ionic deep linking I try to put into practice](http://blog.ionic.io/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/) 
[Ionic deep linking plugin docs for Ionic/Angular 1](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks#ionicangular-1)

I guess it's related to ionic-native's plugin list since it has SQLite also.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, especially the part where dependencies are injected? In your case, that may be the `run()` function.

Comment: Sure but all I did is adding `ionic.native` to the module. Before that everything was working fine. `.run(function ($window, $ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, $cordovaSQLite, $ionicPopup, $ionicHistory) { ... }` and some services are also included.

Comment: try to openDB in `deviceready` event

Comment: Ionic wrapped the `deviceready` into `ionic.Platform.ready()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by changing the way of opening the database. At the time when I was implementing the cordova SQLite database had problems on iOS with `window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase()` but was not using `ionic.native` so back then using the `$cordovaSQLite.openDB()` solved my problem since it calls directly the plugin.

The way I open the db now:
`ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'qpi.db', location: 'default'});
});`